# IntelliJ Cannot start under Java 1.8.0: Java 11 or later is required

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I had some problems with JRE versions, so I tried to change it using the plugin Choose Runtime. I changed it to Java 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2. Now, when trying to start IntelliJ, i get an unsupported Java version error: Cannot start under Java 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2: Java 11 or later is required. I have tried to modify the runtime path in the ide64.exe.jdk file, but it seems like the old jdk IntelliJ ran on has been deleted. I also tried reinstalling intellij, no luck either. Anyone know how to get back the JDK? do I just download it from oracle and install it in the IdeaIC2020.3\jdks\ folder?
Thanks,
Jakob

Comment: Reinstall. This time use one with its own jre

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to the jdks folder and deleted all contents. This fixed the issue. IntelliJ started without a problem.